# Fetch data from studentlist in mongodb to html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
// Get the documents collection
var collection = db.collection('students');

// Find all students
collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  } else if (result.length) {
    res.render('studentlist',{

      // Pass the returned database documents to Jade
      "studentlist" : result
    });
  } else {
    res.send('No documents found');
  }
  //Close connection
  db.close();
});
```

This is my code for finding studentlist in mongodb from collections students.

What is the best way to fetch/print data from studentlist that is in mongodb to the html page?

Comment: Why are you closing connection?

Comment: your question appears to be about "Jade", but there's no related code included